# If a (smooth) deformation of a curve on a surface $S$ preserves geodesic curvature, is it necessarily an isometry of $S$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This seems like it could be false but I can't think of any counter examples. I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider an arbitrary invertible linear map of the plane. It carries lines through the origin (which have $\kappa_g=0$) to other lines through the origin. Yet it's an isometry of the plane only when it's given by an orthogonal matrix (with respect to the standard basis).

Comment: That's true! Thanks